# MSB3721 error when executing yolo_cpp_dll.vcxproj

Tags: visual-studio-2019, darknet, yolov4

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Tool
Error   MSB3721 The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code="sm_30,compute_30" -gencode=arch=compute_75,code="sm_75,compute_75" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu -rdc=true  -I\include -IC:\opencv_3.0\opencv\build\include -I....\include -I....\3rdparty\stb\include -I....\3rdparty\pthreads\include -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I\include -I\include -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static    -DCUDNN_HALF -DCUDNN -DGPU -DLIB_EXPORTS -D_TIMESPEC_DEFINED -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_LIB -D_WINDLL -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Fdx64\DLL_Release\vc142.pdb /FS   /MD " -o x64\DLL_Release\avgpool_layer_kernels.cu.obj "D:\Yolo_v4\darknet\src\avgpool_layer_kernels.cu"" exited with code 1.  yolo_cpp_dll    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 11.2.targets   785     CudaCompile

Answer (score 0):

Support for compute_30 has been removed for versions after CUDA 10.2. So you have to change this lines: **compute_30,sm_30;compute_75,sm_75** in yolo_cpp_dll.vcxproj and darknet.vcxproj to **compute_50,sm_50;compute_75,sm_75**